# Network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, general-network-error

I'm using flutter, and everything was working fine except today. Now, whenever I try to log in, I get this error: **Network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred from FIREBASE on my iOS Simulator.**

And this is the error thrown in my console :

```
Challenge SecTrustResultType 5 for www.googleapis.com, properties: (
        {
          type = error;
          value = "Root certificate is not trusted.";
        }
)
Cancelling authentication challenge for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    "LocalDataTask <59EA3048-54FD-41F4-87FF-4919A55A9E06>.<1>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <59EA3048-54FD-41F4-87FF-4919A55A9E06>.<1>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled} [-999]
```

I have tried everything, googled everything but this is very weird. Since the code was working before, but not working on my system. I guess there is some issues with my simulator. **Checked the date of my simulator**, it is fine.

This is my login code :

```
final AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email: this.email.text, password: this.password.text);
this._auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then((user) async {
  this.gotoHome(context);
}, onError: (e){
     Helpers.showError(context, (e as PlatformException).message);
});
```

**Flutter Doctor Report:**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.5.9-pre.194, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.5.9-pre.194 at /Users/alok/flutter
    • Framework revision 3436e165c8 (6 weeks ago), 2019-05-09 10:37:34 -0700
    • Engine revision 644db5a49c
    • Dart version 2.3.1 (build 2.3.1-dev.0.0 a0290f823c)


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/alok/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.0, Build version 10A255
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4
    • CocoaPods version 1.6.0

[!] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
Aloks-MacBook-Air:newmonkapp alok$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.5.9-pre.194, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132, locale en-US)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.0)
[!] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Also came across with this error included with the above error:

> Encounter network error. Code, error: -999, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
>       "LocalUploadTask .<1>"
>   ), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalUploadTask .<1>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
>   5.16.0 - [GULNetwork][I-NET901017]  Encounter network error. Code, error: -999, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
>       "LocalUploadTask .<1>"
>   ), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalUploadTask .<1>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
>   5.16.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000020] Error posting to Clearcut: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
>       "LocalUploadTask .<1>"
>   ), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalUploadTask .<1>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}, with Status Code: 0

Comment: Today I got the same error. Did you found solution?

Comment: Yeah, there was a mismatch in my firebase core version with the flutter firebase version. What I did was I upgraded the flutter and everything came into place.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered a similar issue but it has nothing to do with the version of the Firebase plugins that I'm using. The issue on my end was caused by restricted API key configured on Google Cloud Console: [https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=[PROJECT_ID]](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=%5BPROJECT_ID%5D)